# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n(1-x) $ not have a convergent majorant series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am working on this problem:

> Find the sum of $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n(1-x), x \in [0,1] $.
>
> Why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n(1-x), x \in [0,1] $ not have a convergent majorant series?

I found the sum to be

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^{n+1} $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^n - x\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^n $$

$$f(x) = \bigg(\frac{1}{1+x}-1 \bigg) -x \bigg(\frac{1}{1+x}-1 \bigg) = \frac{x(x-1)}{x+1} $$

But I can't figure out how to solve the second part of the question. Why does the sum not have a convergent majorant series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|(-1)^{n}x^{n}(1-x)| \leq a_n$ for all $x$ and $n$ then, putting $x=\frac n {n+1}$, we get $(1+\frac  1 n)^{-n} \frac 1  {n+1} \leq a_n$. Use the fact that  $(1+\frac  1 n)^{-n} \to \frac 1 e$ to see that $\sum a_n=\infty$.

How did I think of $x=\frac n {n+1}$? This is just the point where left side is maximized.

Comment: But the left hand side is $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1}$. How can you disregard the term $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and only look at $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n} \leq a_n$, which causes $a_n \not\to 0 \: \: \: \text{for} \: \: \: n \to \infty$ causing $\sum a_n = \infty$?

Comment: @Carl $a_n\geq \frac 1 {2e} \frac 1 {n+1}$ for $n$ sufficiently large and $\sum \frac 1 {2e} \frac 1 {n+1}=\infty$.